# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/img_compass')

Tags: android

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/img_compass').error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/img_compass').

Comment: check that image named img_compass is inside your drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a file named `img_compass` in your project under the structure

`Project -> res - > drawable`

Moreover if that is an image shouldn't it be something like

**img_compass.jpg**

**img_compass.jpeg**

**img_compass.png**